# Read .txt file to listbox without ItemsSource binding OR remove binding without clearing the listbox of the lines

Tags: c#, wpf, text-files, listboxitem, itemssource

I'm fairly new to C# but understand basic concepts.

I'm currently working on a Uni assignment where I have to have multiple textboxes be entered as a single entry in a listbox, then save all entries to a text file. I also need to be able to load the text file and add new entries to the list.

I've figured out how to save data to a .txt file, as well as reloading the .txt file back into the listbox using

```
if (File.Exists("PersonalFile.txt"))
{
 string[] line = File.ReadAllLines("PersonalFile.txt");
 lbxStaffDetails.ItemsSource = line;
}
```

However, doing it this way I can't add new entries to the listbox due to the data binding, I get this error message *System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.'*

Is there a way to remove the binding but keep the data in the listbox? Using `lbxStaffDetails.ItemsSource = null;` clears the listbox; or is there another way to read all lines of the .txt file to the listbox without using the file as a binding source?

Notes:

- lbxStaffDetails is this listbox in question
- PersonalFile.txt is the .txt holding the entries on new lines.
- This is the first time I've bound data and files.

Edit:

Forgot to mention how I'm adding the data to the listbox so here's the code for that.

```
private void btnAddWaitingList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 _EmployeeID = tbxEmployeeID.Text;
 _Name = tbxName.Text;
 _PayRate = tbxPayRate.Text;            
 _Email = tbxEmail.Text;

 string employeeDetails = _EmployeeID + "," + _Name + "," + _PayRate + "," + _Email;

 lbxStaffDetails.Items.Add(employeeDetails);
}
```

As the code fires and gets to the bottom line it throws the error mentioned above.

Comment: There's not enough detail in your question to provide a good answer. But your trouble seems to be rooted in the fact that you're treating your bound model properties incorrectly. Specifically, the _sole purpose_ of the view model containing properties for binding is that those properties reflect what the view should be presenting at any given time. There should be a collection (e.g. `ObservableCollection<string>`) bound to the `ListBox.ItemsSource` (in XAML, not assigned in code-behind), and that collection should be populated by copying to it the data read from the file. ...

Comment: ... The `string[]` returned by `File.ReadAllLines()` is not itself the collection to use for the `ListBox`. Though alternatively, if you do want to use it like that, you should bind `ItemSource` to a `string[]` property in the view model, and update that property with the `string[]` read from the file when reading the file. Other changes to the presentation to the user should be handled similarly, always mediated through a view model, with the underlying "business logic" being handle separately from that view model.

Comment: Since you want to be able to add items to the `ListBox` one at a time as the user enters the data, you probably should go the `ObservableCollection<T>` route. Adding to that collection will automatically update the `ListBox` if you've bound the collection to `ItemsSource` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse data binding with simple value assignment. Data binding is a different concept, where a target binds to a data source using a `Binding`. A `Binding` will monitor target and source and delegates changes from one to the other. It's a bi-directional dynamic data link.
You can setup a `Binding` in XAML or C# (see [Data binding overview in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview)).

You are not binding the `ListBox` to a *file*. You have read contents of a file to an array of strings. This array is then assigned to the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property.

Since you have populated the `ListBox` using the `ItemsSource` property, you are not allowed to modify its items using the `Items` property (`InvalidOperationException`).
You have to either assign the modified collection again to `ListBox.ItemsSource` (which will cause the complete `ListBox` to create all items again, which is bad for the performance) or make use of [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netcore-3.1#remarks).

It's a special collection that allows to be observed (Observer pattern). The observer gets notified by the observed collection via an event that the collection has changed (add/move/remove). Every `ItemsControl` is able to listen to this event and will automatically update itself.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<string> StaffDetails { get; set; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    // Set the DataContext to MainWindow for data binding (XAML version)
    this.DataContext = this;
  }

  private void ReadFile()
  {    
    if (!File.Exists("PersonalFile.txt"))
    {
      return;
    }
     
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("PersonalFile.txt");
    
    // Create a new ObservableCollection and initialize it with the array
    this.StaffDetails = new ObservableCollection<string>(lines);

    // You write to the file using this same collection directly,
    // without accessing the ListBox
    File.WriteAllLines("PersonalFile.txt", this.StaffDetails);
    
    // Option 1: assignment (static data link)
    this.lbxStaffDetails.ItemsSource = this.StaffDetails;
    
    // Alternative option 2: C# data binding (dynamic data link)
    var binding = new Binding(nameof(this.StaffDetails)) { Source = this };
    this.lbxStaffDetails.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
    
    // Alternative option 3 (recommended): XAML data binding (dynamic data link). See MainWindow.xaml
  }

  private void btnAddWaitingList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    _EmployeeID = tbxEmployeeID.Text;
    _Name = tbxName.Text;
    _PayRate = tbxPayRate.Text;            
    _Email = tbxEmail.Text;
    
    var employeeDetails = $"{_EmployeeID},{_Name},{_PayRate},{_Email}";
    
    // Modify the ObservableCollection. 
    // Since ListBox is observing this collection, it will automatically update itself
    this.StaffDetails.Add(employeeDetails);
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>

  <!-- Alternative option 3: XAML data binding (recommended) -->
  <ListBox x:Name="lbxStaffDetails" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding StaffDetails}" />
</Window>
```